# How can we perform an event on key press/key up in application in the background without focus?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to perform this task in the background with interrupting and perform on key press.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    counter++;
    if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
    {
        if (counter != 0)
        {
            using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(@"C:\recycler\temp\system\windows\Logs\" + name + ".txt"))
            {
                write(w);    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

If the key that is pressed is the Enter key, a MessegeBox will displayed .

```
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Enter Key Pressed ");
  }
```

[Control.KeyPress Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Make a click event on the button by clicking it.
remove the click event in button properties so that click event should not be linked with button but there should be its code present in the code file.
your click event of button will looks like

```
timer1_Tick(this, new System.EventArgs());
{
 counter++;
if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
{
    if (counter != 0)
    {
        using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(@"C:\recycler\temp\system\windows\Logs\" + name + ".txt"))
        {
            write(w);    
        }
    }
}
}
```

now just call it on form load event or where you want by this code

```
timer1_Tick(this, new System.EventArgs());
```

or you can also use threads by

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms171728(v=vs.100).aspx